# Message collector in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot that has a "number guessing game" feature.
When I run the bot, it gives me this error:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

It seems like the while loop became an infinite loop. This is my code (all the functions and variables are declared)

```
while (numberOfGuesses < 5) {
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 10000,
    max: 1
  });
  collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (guess.length == 0 || !guessInRange(guess)) {
      message.channel.send('please say 1~100');
    } else {
      if (parseInt(guess) == secretNumber) {
        message.channel.send('Boom! Correct!');
        return collector.stop();
      } else if (parseInt(guess) < secretNumber) {
        numberOfGuesses++;
        message.channel.send('Too small');
        collector.stop();
      } else {
        numberOfGuesses++;
        message.channel.send('Too big');
        collector.stop();

      }
      if (numberOfGuesses == 5) {
        collector.stop();
        return message.channel.send('Game over');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Nothing is blocking execution, so what is happening is a new collector is being added to the stack every iteration. Then, you run out of memory. Declaring the collector outside of the loop will quickly solve your problem, but you probably want to use a different approach. I'll elaborate in second if someone else doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

the reason is cause the while loop runs *really fast*. While the messages come in slow.
So by the time 5 "guesses" come, the loop could've ran a million times. therby making a million collectors as well.

try this:

```
function getGuesses(numberOfGuesses,maxGuesses){
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 10000, max: 1 });
    collector.on('collect', message => {
        if (guess.length == 0 || ! guessInRange(guess)) {
            message.channel.send('please say 1~100');                
        } else {
            if (parseInt(guess) == secretNumber) {
                message.channel.send('Boom! Correct!');
                return collector.stop();
            } else if (parseInt(guess) < secretNumber) {
                numberOfGuesses++;
                message.channel.send('Too small');
                collector.stop();
            } else {
                numberOfGuesses++;
                message.channel.send('Too big');
                collector.stop();

            }
            if (numberOfGuesses == maxGuesses) {
                collector.stop();
                return message.channel.send('Game over');
            }
        }   
    });

    //Repeat if guesses still exist
    collector.on('end', collected => {
        if(numberOfGuessed < maxGuesses) getGuesses(numberOfGuesses,maxGuesses)
    });
};

getGuesses(0,5);
```

Comment: You still might need to block execution while waiting for the 5 guesses. Any empty while loop awaiting numberOfGuesses to equal maxGuesses or the collector to be closed at the bottom of this function could do

Comment: true. but that isn't the problem he's requesting... nor will that fix his error. The solution I provided only fixed his problem.