# How to loop message collectors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a fight command with Discord.js. I've tried using `while` and `for` loops but they don't work. Here's my code so far:

```
    db.set(`p2name_${message.channel.id}`, message.mentions.users.first().username);
    db.set(`p2id_${message.channel.id}`, message.mentions.users.first().id);
    db.set(`p1name_${message.channel.id}`, message.author.username);

    let p2id = db.fetch(`p2id_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p2name = db.fetch(`p2name_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p1name = db.fetch(`p1name_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p1health = 100;
    let p2health = 100;
    let p1turn = true;
    let p2turn = false;

    const gstart = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === message.mentions.users.first().id, { time: 3600000 });
    const p1 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 100000 });
    const p2 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === message.mentions.users.first().id, { time: 100000 });

    message.channel.send(`${p2name}, do you accept the challenge?`)
    gstart.on('collect', message => {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
        message.channel.send(`${p2name} has accepted the challenge!`)
        gstart.stop();


        message.channel.send(`${p1name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)

        function a() {
          p1.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "punch") {
              p2health = p2health - rng.random(1, 50)
              if (p2health === 0) return message.channel.send(`${p1name} wins with ${p1health}! Congratulations!`)
              message.channel.send(`${p2name}, your health is now ${p2health}.`)
              p1.stop();
              message.channel.send(`${p2name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)
                .then(() => {
                  p2.on('collect', message => {
                    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "punch") {
                      p1health = p1health - rng.random(1, 70)
                      if (p1health === 0) return message.channel.send(`${p2name} wins with ${p2health}! Congratulations!`);
                      message.channel.send(`${p1name}, your health is now ${p1health}.`)
                      p2.stop()
                      message.channel.send(`${p1name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)
                    }
                  })
                })
            }
          })

        

      }

        while (p1health !== 0 && p2health !== 0) {
          a();
        }
        
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`${p1name}, ${p2name} has declined your challenge.`);
        gstart.stop();
      }
    })
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Whenever my alt says yes my bot stops running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after some digging I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965878/message-collector-in-while-loop) post.

After reading through said post I came up with this answer.

```
    db.set(`p2name_${message.channel.id}`, message.mentions.users.first().username);
    db.set(`p2id_${message.channel.id}`, message.mentions.users.first().id);
    db.set(`p1name_${message.channel.id}`, message.author.username);
    db.set(`p1id_${message.channel.id}`, message.author.id);
    // variables
    let p2id = db.fetch(`p2id_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p1id = db.fetch(`p1id_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p2name = db.fetch(`p2name_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p1name = db.fetch(`p1name_${message.channel.id}`);
    let p1health = 100;
    let p2health = 100;
    // constants

    const gstart = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === message.mentions.users.first().id, { time: 3600000 });
    const p1 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === p1id, { time: 100000 });
    const p2 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === p2id, { time: 100000 });

    message.channel.send(`${p2name}, do you accept the challenge?`)
    gstart.on('collect', message => {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
        message.channel.send(`${p2name} has accepted the challenge!`)
        gstart.stop();


        message.channel.send(`${p1name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)

        function a() {
          const p1 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === p1id, { time: 100000 });
          const p2 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === p2id, { time: 100000 });
          p1.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "punch") {
              p2health = p2health - rng.random(1, 50)
              if (p2health <= 0) return message.channel.send(`${p1name} wins with ${p1health} health! Congratulations!`)
              message.channel.send(`${p2name}, your health is now ${p2health}.`)
              p1.stop();
              message.channel.send(`${p2name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)
                .then(() => {
                  p2.on('collect', message => {
                    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "punch") {
                      p1health = p1health - rng.random(1, 70)
                      if (p1health <= 0) return message.channel.send(`${p2name} wins with ${p2health} health! Congratulations!`);
                      message.channel.send(`${p1name}, your health is now ${p1health}.`)
                      p2.emit('end')
                      message.channel.send(`${p1name}, what do you want to do? \`Punch\``)
                    }
                  })
                })
            }
          })
        
        p2.on('end', () => {
          if (p1health !== 0 || p2health !== 0) {
            a();
          }
        })

      }


      a();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate method that you can try without having to put `message` event listeners inside of each other. Basically, I'm using the [`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) method that returns a promise and placing it inside of a `try...catch` block.

Code Example - Modify it accordingly to your needs:

```js
try {
    //either create a filter here or put it outside, I didn't include one in the code
    let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] }); //waits for 10 seconds
    console.log(msg.first().content); //logs the message content it receives
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    message.channel.send('You ran out of time!');
}
```